# Unable to Install GDAL Python Binding with PIP

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, homebrew

I am trying to install GDAL Python Package in my macOS Sonoma(14.4), but each time I am trying to install I get an error which is mentioned below:

Few last lines of the Installation Message:

````
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:6: note: insert '_Nullable' if the pointer may be null
      FILE    *funopen(const void *,
              ^
                _Nullable
      /usr/local/include/stdio.h:386:6: note: insert '_Nonnull' if the pointer should never be null
      FILE    *funopen(const void *,
              ^
                _Nonnull
      193 warnings and 20 errors generated.
      extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:2749:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        for (i =0; i < swig_module->size; ++i) {
                ^
      extensions/gdalconst_wrap.c:2747:5: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
      if( 1 )
          ^
          /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      193 warnings and 20 errors generated.
      193 warnings and 20 errors generated.
      193 warnings and 20 errors generated.
      193 warnings generated.
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/extensions/gdalconst_wrap.o -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.8.4_3/lib -lgdal -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-311/osgeo/_gdalconst.cpython-311-darwin.so
      ld: warning: ignoring file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.8.4_3/lib/libgdal.34.3.8.4.dylib': found architecture 'arm64', required architecture 'x86_64'
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gdal
Failed to build gdal
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gdal, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```
````